# API Новая Почта

Tags: javascript, новая-почта

На сайте [Новая Почта](https://devcenter.novaposhta.ua/docs/services/556d7ccaa0fe4f08e8f7ce43/operations/58e5ebeceea27017bc851d67) указан пример кода JavaScript привод  фрагмент:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://testapi.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/{format}/Address/searchSettlements/?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            },
            type: "POST",
            // Request body
            data: "{body}",
        })
```

Вопрос: что прописать место

> data: "{body}" ?

Comment: Вероятно, MIME-документ, если команда НовойПочты состоит не совсем из поросят. Как его формировать на JS - отдельный вопрос. Можно и вручную, это не столь сложно.

Answer (score 2):

```
var settings = {
    "apiKey": "[ВАШ КЛЮЧ]"
    , "modelName": "Address"
    , "calledMethod": "getAreas"
    , "methodProperties": {}
}
```

И потом

```
data: JSON.stringify(settings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо "body" нужно передавать запрос.
Пример:

```
data: {
"apiKey": "[ВАШ КЛЮЧ]",
 "modelName": "Address",
    "calledMethod": "searchSettlements",
    "methodProperties": {
        "CityName": "київ",
        "Limit": 5
    }
}
```

Только это все нежно передавать в json'не, а как в javascript это переформатировать я не знаю.